# TypeError: string indices must be integers, while trying to convert json into csv

Tags: python, json, csv, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am getting this error upon running the below code

```py
import json
import csv
with open ("sample-json-file.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    
fname = "output.csv"

with open(fname,"w") as file:
    csv_file =csv.writer(file)
    csv_file.writerow(["Name", "Mobile", "Boolean", "Country"])
    for item in data:
        csv_file.writerow([item['name'], item['mobile'], item['boolean'], item['country']])
```

My json file has the following content-

```py
{
   "Name": "Test",
   "Mobile": 12345678,
   "Boolean": "true",
   "Pets": ["Dog", "cat"],
   "country" : "India"
}
```

Please suggest what changes are to be made, I would be very grateful.

## Traceback

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-9719807e095c> in <module>
      8     csv_file.writerow(["Name", "Mobile", "Boolean", "Country"])
      9     for item in data:
---> 10         csv_file.writerow([item['name'], item['mobile'], item['boolean'], item['country']])

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: I don't think that's representative of your JSON. If you try iterate that like a list, you'll just get the keys (strings) so the error makes sense. But you wouldn't have a `for` loop if there wasn't a collection to go through. The plot thickens...

Comment: Your json file is a single dict, not a list of dicts. Are you intending on writing a single row? Or is your real data a list of dicts?

Comment: A second problem in your code is that the JSON has capitalized names but your indexing does not. JSON: `"Name": "Test"` means `data['name']` would raise an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## If the data is a single `dict` in a file

- Given the data in this example
- Using your code as presented
- `for item in data:` is not needed because you are already writing the keys from data and there is nothing to iterate through.

```py
with open ("test.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    
fname = "output.csv"

with open(fname,"w") as file:
    csv_file =csv.writer(file)
    csv_file.writerow(["Name", "Mobile", "Boolean", "Country"])
    csv_file.writerow([data['Name'], data['Mobile'], data['Boolean'], data['country']])
```

## If the data is a `list` of `dicts` in a file, as follows:

```py
[ {
        "Name": "Test",
        "Mobile": 12345678,
        "Boolean": "true",
        "Pets": ["Dog", "cat"],
        "country": "India"
    }, {
        "Name": "Test",
        "Mobile": 12345678,
        "Boolean": "true",
        "Pets": ["Dog", "cat"],
        "country": "India"
    }]
```

- Now `for item in data:` is needed to loop through each `dict` in the list

```py
with open ("test.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

fname = "output.csv"

with open(fname,"w") as file:
    csv_file =csv.writer(file)
    csv_file.writerow(["Name", "Mobile", "Boolean", "Country"])
    for item in data:
        csv_file.writerow([item['Name'], item['Mobile'], item['Boolean'], item['country']])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example json is a single `dict`. When you try to iterate it, you get the dictionary keys (in your case, strings) and of course `"name"["name"]` isn't a thing. You could remove the `for` loop (its just 1 dict, not a list of dicts) and `writerow(data['nmae'], ..)` but `csv` has a `DictWriter` class you can use instead.

```
import json
import csv
with open ("sample-json-file.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

fname = "output.csv"

fieldnames = ["Name", "Mobile", "Boolean", "Country"]

with open(fname,"w") as file:
    csv_file =csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore')
    csv_file.writeheader()
    csv_file.writerow(data)
```